# SQL statement to format the table data

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a below table and need to get theoutput using plain sql as shown below 2. If the `columnC` does have 'Y' for *any* of the  same value of `ColumnA`, the success count should be +1 else it should be added to fail count column of the output. Can we write a SQL (in Oracle) to get the output as mentioned below? `ColumnD` can be ignored for now.

## 1. Table

```
ColumnA   ColumnB    ColumnC    ColumnD     File_type
--------  ---------  --------   ----------  ------------
11111     A          N          NULL        typeA
11111     B          N          NULL        typeA
11111     C          Y          SPILL       null
11111     D          N          NULL        typeA
22222     A          N          SPILL       typeA
22222     B          Y          SPILL       typeA
22222     C          N          NULL        null
22222     D          N          NULL        typeA
33333     A          N          NULL        typeA
33333     B          N          NULL        null
33333     C          N          NULL        typeA
33333     D          N          NULL        typeA
111110    A          N          NULL        typeB
111110    B          N          NULL        typeB
111110    C          Y          SPILL       null
111110    D          N          NULL        typeB
222220    A          N          SPILL       typeB
222220    B          Y          SPILL       typeB
222220    C          N          NULL        null
222220    D          N          NULL        typeB
333330    A          N          NULL        typeB
333330    B          N          NULL        null
333330    C          Y          SPILL       typeB
333330    D          N          NULL        typeB
```

**2. Required Output**

```
File_type        ColumnD  Success_cnt    Fail_cnt
----------       -------- -----------    -----------
typeA             SPILL         2          1
typeB             SPILL         3
```

Comment: What have you already tried?  Are you familiar with `CASE` clause?

Comment: What do you mean by "*plain SQL*"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my attempt to understand your task:

```
SELECT r.File_type, SUM(CASE WHEN r.cnt > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) success, 
                    SUM(CASE WHEN r.cnt = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) fail
FROM
(SELECT t.File_type,  SUM(CASE WHEN t.ColumnC = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) cnt
FROM Table1 t
WHERE t.File_type IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY t.file_type, t.ColumnA) r
GROUP BY r.File_type;
```

I did not use `ColumnB` and `ColumnC` at all.

Here's [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/60b35/1) for this task.  I used a reduced data sample. You may want to try it with different data.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
with CTE as
(
    select A.columnA, columnc,
    row_number() over (partition by columnA order by columnc desc) rnk
    from T  A  
), cte2 as
(
    SELECT distinct columna, file_type from t where file_type is not null
), cte3 as
(
     select distinct columnd, file_type from t 
     where file_type is not null and columnd is not null
)
select a.file_type, a.columnd, 
count(case when columnc = 'Y' then 1 end) Success_cnt,
count(case when columnc = 'N' then 1 end) fail_cnt
from cte3 a 
inner join cte2 b on a.file_type = b.file_type
inner join
(select * from cte where rnk = 1) c on b.columnA = c.columnA
group by a.file_type, a.columnd
```

[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1ed45/28)

Comment: Not what OP asked for. Though the result incidentally will look the same.

Comment: @PM77-1 can you explain what did OP ask for?

Comment: (1) OP indicated that `ColumnD` does not play any role (2) my understanding that we need to look at rows with the same `ColumnA` value and if **any** of these rows have "Y" in `ColumnB` then we increment `Success`, otherwise we increment `Fail`.

Comment: @PM77-1, did you see his required output?

Comment: @ rs. - Yes, I did.  "11111" and "222222" have "Y", so we have 2 for success, "333333" have none, so 1 for fail.

Comment: I'm neither OP nor a mind reader so feel free to disregard my comments. It would be much better if we could get clarification from OP.

Comment: @PM77-1 according to your explanation fail_cnt should be 10 not 1

Comment: @PM77-1  This is not as simple as you wrote, it needs a subquery for sure and might need pivot for adding success_cnt or fail_cnt

Comment: @rs. - No. One count per the entire block (not individual row).

Comment: @user1595858 - Then **please** post the exact detailed specs. So far I see that it will need `SELF JOIN` but do not see a need for `PIVOT`.  What is my interpretation missing?

Comment: @PM77-1 i just did a final modification. I think you are pretty close. Not necessary it needs a PIVOT but you can post your best answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore the columnA output, or else run this in an outer select as a derived table...

```
SELECT
   ColumnA,
   File_type,
   CountIf(Max(ColumnC),'Y') as "Success_cnt",
   CountIf(Max(ColumnC),'N') as "Fail_cnt"
FROM
   table
Group By
   ColumnA,
   File_type
```

Comment: You will not get the same output as OP requested.

Comment: Please see my comments for "rs" answer.

Comment: @卵が好き This is not that simple.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to use cursor. You can loop through the records and get a variable incremented based on your needs. Have you tried this already ?